# How to calculate number of days in last 3 months

Tags: php, date

How we can calculate, number of days in last 3 months?

i.e. - today is `11-11-2013`

I want to calculate total number of days from `1st September` to `today`; i.e. 72 days.

1st November wil change automatically.

Comment: **[Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2040626/67332)**

Comment: How will `1st November` change automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

     $now = time(); // or your date as well
     $your_date = strtotime("2010-01-01");
     $datediff = $now - $your_date;
     echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));

?>
```

You can also check **[this link](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)**.

Answer (score 1):

For exact time try this

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-09-01 12:00:00');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-11-11 12:00:00');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo $interval->m . " Month " .$interval->d ." Days ". $interval->h . " Hours, " . $interval->i." Mintues, ".$interval->s." seconds ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date('d') + cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m') -1 , date('y')) + cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, date('m') -2 , date('y'));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$currentDate = mktime(0, 0, 0 , date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));<br/>
$last3Months = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") - 3, date("d"), date("Y"));<br/>
$diff = $currentDate - $last3Months;<br/>
echo $diff/(60*60*24);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$today  =   strtotime("+1 day");
$beforeThreeMonth   =   date("M-Y",strtotime("-2 month"));
$beforeThreeMonthDate   =   strtotime($beforeThreeMonth);

$timeStampInterval  =   $today-$beforeThreeMonthDate;

echo floor($timeStampInterval/(60*60*24));
```